# JAVA quicksort ,what is the mistake in partition method?

Tags: java, quicksort

```
/**
     * Sort an array in ascending order
     * @param arr array to sort
     */
    public static void quickSort(int[] arr){
        qs(arr, 0, arr.length);
    }

/**
     * Sort a region of an array in ascending order.
     * Elements outside the given region are unchanged.
     * requires: 0 <= start <= end <= arr.length
     * @param arr   array to sort
     * @param start start of region (inclusive)
     * @param end   end of region (exclusive)
     */
    private static void qs(int[] arr, int start, int end){
        if (end <= start+1){    //region of length 0 or 1
            return;
        }
        int x = arr[start];
        int p = partition(arr, start+1, end, x);
            //now swap arr[start] with arr[p-1]
        arr[start] = arr[p-1];
        arr[p-1] = x;
        qs(arr, start, p-1);
        qs(arr, p, end);



    }

    /**
     * Partition a region of an array.
     * Rearranges elements in region so that small ones
     *   all have smaller indexes than the big ones.
     * Elements outside the region are unchanged.
     * requires: 0 <= start <= end <= arr.length
     * @param arr   array to partition
     * @param start start of region (inclusive)
     * @param end   end of region (exclusive)
     * @param x     pivot - "small" and "big" are <x, >=x.
     * @return      start index (inclusive) of big elements
     *              in region after partition.
     */
    private static int partition(
        int[] arr, int start, int end, int x)
    {

        int l = start -1, r = end+1;
        while (true) {
            while (l < end && arr[++l] < x) ;

            while(r> l && arr[--r] >x);// find smaller item

                if(l >= r) // if pointers cross,
                    break; // partition done
                    else  {
                        int temp;
                temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[r];
                arr[r] = temp;
            }
        }
        return l;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {15,8,9,6,2,8,8,5,8,4,2};
        quickSort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the mistake in the `partition` method?

Comment: it throws arrayindexoutofbounds exception

Comment: On what line? What does the stack trace say?

Answer (score 2):

Let me highlight a few important facts:

```
 * @param end   end of region (exclusive)
                               ^^^^^^^^^

 * @param x     pivot - "small" and "big" are <x, >=x.
 * @return      start index (inclusive) of big elements
 *              in region after partition.
 */
private static int partition(
    int[] arr, int start, int end, int x)
{

    int l = start -1, r = end+1;
                      ^^^^^^^^^^

    while (true) {
        while (l < end && arr[++l] < x) ;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        while(r> l && arr[--r] >x);// find smaller item
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

When the entire array is partitioned, `end` is `arr.length`. Then you set `end = arr.length + 1` and after incrementing the lower index `l` as far as the loop takes it, if that didn't raise an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (trying to access `arr[end]` if the pivot is e.g. the maximal element in the array), the first array element you try to access in the next loop is `arr[arr.length]`. That raises an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So you're guaranteed to get an AIOBE in `partition`.

You could set `r = end` and change your loop controls to

```
while(++l < r && arr[l] < x)
```

and

```
while(r-- > l && arr[r] > x)
```

or you could make the higher index inclusive too and call `qs(arr, 0, arr.length -1)` from `main`.

Comment: i think i need to to make r=end +1 and change the loop because i leave r=end the last index will left unchanged

Comment: You want `r` to start one after the chunk of the array to partition. That means, either `end` is inclusive, and you start with `r = end+1`, or `end` is exclusive, and `r` starts with `end`. You have the choice. Well, there are the more conventional variants with the increment and decrement in the loop body rather than the loop control.

Comment: start <= l <= r <= end  this is the loop invariant and im suppose to do it like this

Comment: or i can leave r=end;  and change the loop to                    while(++l < r+1 && arr[l] < x)   ,nevertheless im suppose to do it like that start <= l <= r <= end